# How to rip Audio-CD to mp3 in Linux console?

Tags: linux, mp3

I' looking for tool that convert Audio-CD to mp3 in Linux console - ONE good tool.
Using cdparanoia + lame is ok, but... is something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cdparanoia functions use cdparanoia. cdparanoia [doesn't compress](http://xiph.org/paranoia/faq.html#gimme). There is a 6 year old integration script called [dekagen](http://www.mbayer.de/dekagen/) which might still work or could probably work with slight updating.

Happy ripping (all the cool kids are using [Ogg/Vorbis](http://www.vorbis.com/) now).

Answer (score 1):

The "UNIX way" (and by extension the Linux way) is to combine single-purpose tools that do their job well using pipes or scripting, rather than writing redundant tools with overlapping functionality. A single ripping tool would have to duplicate both the functionality of cdparanoia for audio extraction, and the functionality of LAME for MP3 encoding, which is a waste of effort unless the new single tool was going to perform some important new task which could not be achieved with the existing combination.

Using cdparanoia and LAME is therefore absolutely the *right* way to accomplish this. If you perform this task often and want to streamline the process, you might consider writing a script that invokes the tools with the necessary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Found [RipIT](http://www.suwald.com/ripit/news.php), but have not tried yet.

> RipIT is used to create MPEG-1 Layer 3 (mp3) using Lame, or uses Flac (flac), Ogg Vorbis (ogg), Faac (m4a), Musepack (mpc), mp4als (als), Wavpack (wv) or ffmpeg to convert audio files (wav) extracted from an audio CD. It is a console based front-end (no GUI here), written in Perl.